# MYSQL return results where there exist at least one from the other table

Tags: mysql

Say I have these data from two table:

Student Table columns:

```
id | name
```

Course Table columns:

```
id | code | name
```

and I want to use the Student.id AS Student and Course.id AS Course
to get the following:

```
Student | Course
-----------------  
1       |   C
1       |   B
1       |   A
2       |   F
2       |   B
2       |   A
3       |   C
3       |   B
3       |   F
```

How would I query it so it will return only the Students with a Course C and their other Courses like below:

```
Student | Course
-----------------  
1       |   C
1       |   B
1       |   A
3       |   C
3       |   B
3       |   F
```

?
I have tried :

```
SELECT Student.id, Course.code FROM Course 
INNER JOIN Student ON Course.student = Student.id
WHERE Course.code = 'C'
```

but I got only

```
Student | Course
-----------------  
1       |   C
3       |   C
```

Comment: Your `FROM` clause references two tables, `Course, Student`, but above you only show one table with two columns. Which is it? Please post the definitions of both tables.

Comment: I have mentioned at the start that the first table is from two tables. I just added description after it to show how they relate.

Comment: I know you mentioned it at the start, but to help the people below trying to write effective answers with the right column names, you should post the structures of those two tables. The first answer you got (now deleted) was based on the appearance of _one_ table. It's just for clarity.

Comment: You don't need two tables here in fact. Both student id and course name are present in Course table. Please see my answer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowki apologies, it makes sense now. Do you think the question makes more sense now?

Comment: @sashkello Hi thanks. I am quering two table. I think my question was a bit misleading as Michael mentioned, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  s.id, c.code 
FROM    Course c
        INNER JOIN Student s
            ON c.student = s.id
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    Course c1
            WHERE   c.student = c1.student
                    AND c1.Course = 'C'
        )
```

Comment: Note that with large sets, a query of this form (with a correlated subquery in an EXISTS predicate, usually doesn't perform as well as a JOIN operation) because of the way MySQL processes that. For every row returned by the outer query, MySQL executes the subquery. For small sets, we don't notice a difference, but with large sets, the difference becomes noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient approach to this problem is usually an inline view and a JOIN operation, although there are several ways to get an equivalent result.

```
SELECT Student.id
     , Course.code 
  FROM ( SELECT c.Student
           FROM Course c
          WHERE c.code = 'C'
          GROUP BY c.Student
       ) o
 JOIN Course
   ON Course.Student = o.Student
 JOIN Student
   ON Student.id = Course.Student
```

Here, we're using an inline view (aliased as o) to get a list of Student taking course code = 'C'.

(NOTE: the query in my answer is based on your original query. If there's a foreign key definition between Course and Student, and we only need to return the Student.id, we could improve performance by omitting the join to Student, and return `Course.Student AS id` in place of `Student.id` in the SELECT list.)

Comment: Hi spencer7593! Thank you for your approach it worked like a charm, only I preferred John's as it was personally quicker for me to understand.

Comment: @obsessiveCookie: be warned that the correlated subquery in the EXISTS predicate can "eat your lunch", in terms of performance, for large sets, because of how MySQL processes that... for every row returned by the outer query, MySQL executes the subquery in the EXISTS predicate, and all those execution can get expensive for very large sets. For small sets, you won't notice a difference in performance.

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense. I am only working with small sets for the meantime but I will keep that in mind. Thank you for being so helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here the first JOIN selects only those students which have course C, and second JOIN gives you all the courses for each of those students.

```
SELECT st.id, c2.code FROM 
Student st 
JOIN Course c ON c.student = st.id AND c.code = "C"
JOIN Course c2 ON c2.student = st.id
```

---

You actually don't even need two tables here, because both student and course is available in the Course table, just JOIN it on itself:

```
SELECT c2.student, c2.code FROM 
Course c JOIN Course c2 ON c.student = c2.student
WHERE c.course = "C"
```

Here the WHERE clause leaves student id's which have course C and then you JOIN those to find all their courses.